# What is the easiest way to initialize a 2d array from a vector of strings?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
vector<string> myVector = {0};

myVector.push_back("first");
myVector.push_back("second");

char *list[] = ????
```

I want it to be initialized like if I was doing this

```
char *list[] = { "first", "second", NULL };
```

I know I can start allocating memory based on the size and of the vector and the size of the longest string in the vector (`list[v.size()+1][longest_string_in_vector]`) but I wanted to see I'm not thinking of something that might be easier/faster.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? It is *usually* a bad idea to use `char*` in C++, and `char*[]` is even worse.

Comment: I have to support legacy code.

Comment: Is it really possible ?

Comment: then post the use cases, the legacy API.  there might be better workarounds.

Comment: @Pittfall You may not declare variable length arrays in C++. Such a code will not be C++ compliant.

Comment: @Pittfall Does the legacy code requires a `char**`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes the legacy code requires `char**`.  I'm not happy about but it's a method used to build a ui list from this `char**`.  my only other choice is to rewrite it.... Instead I chose to add a wrapper.

Comment: @Pitfall -- does the legacy function change any of the strings, or is the parameter really only a "read only" array?  In other words, your individual strings are actually constant, and won't be altered by the legacy function (I'm assuming this, since you originally had string-literals in the array list).

Comment: @Pitfall -- see my answer and note the caveats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the legacy code requires a `char **`, then to create a variable list, you can create a vector as you initially are doing in your question.

After that, create a `std::vector<char *>`, where the pointers are pointers within the vector for each item.  Of course, you have to ensure that the vector doesn't go out of scope or is resized.  It has to be fully "set up" before creating the `std::vector<char *>`.

In addition, since you are certain that the legacy function does not attempt to alter the strings sent to it, we should take away the "constness" of the strings.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void legacy_function(char **myList) 
{
     for (int i = 0; myList[i]; ++i)
          std::cout << myList[i] << "\n";
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<string> myVector;
    myVector.push_back("first");
    myVector.push_back("second");
    //...
    // create the pointer vector
    vector<char *> myPtrVector;
    // add pointer to string to vector
    for (size_t i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i)
       myPtrVector.push_back(const_cast<char*>(myVector[i].c_str()));
    // stick the null at the end
    myPtrVector.push_back(NULL);
    // ...
    // call legacy function
    legacy_function(&myPtrVector[0]);
}
```

Basically, we created the strings in a vector, and created another vector that stores pointers to the strings.

Note that the function `legacy_function` takes a `char **`, and all we need to do is pass it the address of the first element in our pointer vector.

Live Example: http://ideone.com/77oNns

Edit: Rather than having the code strewn in different areas of your program, a better approach in terms of code organization is to encapsulate the creation of the array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class CharPtrPtr
{
   std::vector<std::string> m_args;
   std::vector<char *> m_argsptr;

   public:
       void add(const std::string& s) { m_args.push_back(s); }

       char ** create_argsPtr() 
       { 
          m_argsptr.clear();
          for (size_t i = 0; i < m_args.size(); ++i)
             m_argsptr.push_back(const_cast<char*>(m_args[i].c_str()));
          m_argsptr.push_back(NULL);
          return &m_argsptr[0]; 
       }

       char **get_argsPtr() { return m_argsptr.empty()?NULL:&m_argsptr[0]; }

       void clear_args() { m_args.clear(); m_argsptr.clear(); }
};


#include <iostream>

void legacy_function(char **myList) 
{
    for (int i = 0; myList[i]; ++i)
        std::cout << myList[i] << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    CharPtrPtr args;
    args.add("first");
    args.add("second");
    legacy_function(args.create_argsPtr());
}
```

Live Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/834afa665f054a1f

Comment: excellent examples! This is exactly what I was looking for.  Let C++ do the work rather than me manually allocating memory.  Easier to read and less chances of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these two ways,

1.Initialize manually

```
char *list[] = { (char*)&myVector[0][0], (char*)&myVector[1][0] };
```

2.Initialize in a loop

```
char **list2 = new char*[ myVector.size() ];
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i ) {
    list2[ i ] = (char*)&myVector[ i ][0];
}
```

However these lists only have pointers to the each string  in the vector and don't actually have a copy. If you change the strings, you'll see the changes from the lists. But if you empty the vector then the lists will have a dangling pointer.

3.If you want a copy of the strings then,

```
char **list = new char*[ myVector.size() ];
for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); ++i ) {
    list[ i ] = new char[myVector[i].size()+1];
    strcpy( list[ i ], &myVector[i][0] );
}
```

I wouldn't write this code but, there you go..

Comment: this is not a nice solution.  It does not handle a dynamic size for the vector and I'm not trying to be mean but it looks ugly too.  Solution by PaulMckenzie is a pretty nice one.

Comment: My second solution does the same thing as Paul's vector. But indeed, Paul's answer is more elegant. You're not mean, I would've said it so myself: that code is ugly but since you're using legacy code, I wrote it that way.